# Solve $\log_3(1/\sqrt{\log_3(x)})=\log_9(\log_9(x/3))$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

How can I solve the equation
$$\log_3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_3(x)}}\right)=\log_9\left(\log_9\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)$$
I tried this
$$\log_3(1)-\log_3\left(\sqrt{\log_3(x)}\right)=\log_9(\log_9(x)-\log_9(3))$$
$$-\log_3\left(\sqrt{\log_3(x)}\right)=\log_9(\log_9(x)-1/2)$$
$$-\log_3\left(\sqrt{\log_3(x)}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\log_3\left(\frac{1}{2}\log_3(x)-1/2\right)$$
But I can't continue.

Comment: Actually in the first step you have $\log_3(1)-\log_3(\log_3(x))$. Further, your left hand side in the title looks different from the one in the question.

Comment: It's fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have that $$\begin{align}\log_3\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log_3(x)}}\right)=\log_9\left(\log_9\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)\right)&\implies \ln\left(\sqrt{\frac{\ln3}{\ln x}}\right)=\frac{\ln\left(\ln\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)/\ln9\right)}{2}\\&\implies \sqrt{\frac{\ln3}{\ln x}}=\sqrt{\ln\left(\frac{x}{3}\right)/\ln9}\\&\implies \ln3\ln9=\ln x\ln\frac x3\end{align}$$ From which we see that an obvious solution is $x=9$.

Comment: Can you please explain this in a little bit more detail? Like showing more fundamental steps, for example. It's too hard to follow it like this.

Comment: Nevermind, I understand it now.

Comment: Great! :) ${}{}$